# Why is Mocha & Chia unit test failing to catch expected error in web-component constructor?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, web-component, typescript

I have a unit testing set up using Mocha and Chia run in a Chrome browser as shown below. To enforce the Component class' static htmlTagName property, I am using an error in the Component base-class that gets thrown if the htmlTagName property is not overwritten by a child class. The problem that I am encountering is that the error thrown in the constructor does not appear to be caught by chia.assert.throw(...) instead it causes the test to fail as shown in the link below. The behavior I expected to see is that chia catches the expected error and the test passes. I have included the relevant code below.

[Unit-test error result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg1Lv.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mocha Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script src="../../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script type="module" class="mocha-init">mocha.setup('bdd')</script>

    <!-- load code you want to test here -->

    <!-- load your test files here -->
    <script type='module' src="./objective-styles.test.js"></script>
    <script type='module' src="./base-classes.test.js"></script>
    <script type='module' src="./calendar-widget.test.js"></script>

    <script type="module">
      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
//base-classes.ts
export class Component extends HTMLElement {

    static htmlTagName: string | undefined;

    constructor() {
        super();

        // Enforce classes having htmlTagName
        if(!this.htmlTagName) {
            throw (`${this.constructor.name} htmlTagName property is undefined`);
        }
    }

    get htmlTagName() {
        return this.constructor.htmlTagName;
    }

    set htmlTagName(htmlTagName: string) {
        this.constructor.htmlTagName = htmlTagName;
    }
}
```

```js
// base-classes.test.ts
import { GuiTestingUtils } from "./gui-testing-utils.js";
import { Component, Widget} from "../../app/js/widgets/base-classes.js";


describe("Component test suite", ()=>{

    let sandbox: HTMLDivElement;
    let fakeDOM: ShadowRoot;
    let style: HTMLStyleElement;

    before(()=>{
        // set up the sandbox
        let body = document.querySelector('body');
        sandbox = GuiTestingUtils.addSandbox(body!);
        fakeDOM = sandbox.shadowRoot!;
        style = document.createElement('style');
    });

    beforeEach(()=>{
        // clean the sandbox
        GuiTestingUtils.refreshSandbox(sandbox);
        fakeDOM.appendChild(style);
    });

    after(()=>{
        // tear down the sandbox
        let body = document.querySelector('body');
        body!.removeChild(sandbox);
    });

    it("Component does throw error if htmlTagName is not defined", ()=>{
        // chia.assert.throw does not catch the error as expected...
        customElements.define("base-component", Component);
        chai.assert.throw(()=>{
            document.createElement("base-component");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my **Jasmine** tests. I suspect it is because the actual initialization of the object is done by the browser when you add the component to the DOM.